# gpgtar: encrypted packet with unknown version

Tags: tar, gpg

I'm getting the error in the title (`aead encrypted packet with unknown version 29`), when trying to decrypt an encrypted file created in the same environment (Termux on Android, if it matters):

```
$ gpgtar --encrypt --output e -r attilio test
$ ls
e test
$ gpgtar -d e
gpgtar: gpg: encrypted with cv25519 key, ID 74341D598FFF0056, created 2021-08-13
gpgtar: gpg:       "attilio"
gpgtar: gpg: public key decryption failed: Not a typewriter
gpgtar: gpg: decryption failed: Not a typewriter
gpgtar: gpg: aead encrypted packet with unknown version 29
gpgtar: error running '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/gpg': exit status 2
```

I got the usage from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54010732/3398271).

**Question:** what does this error even mean, and how can I fix it?

([Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22encrypted%20packet%20with%20unknown%20version%22) only show the source code, so I guess it does not happen all that often.)

Answer (score 0):

Meta: not an answer yet, but too much for comments.

Your *first* two errors, `[public key] decryption failed: not a typewriter`, almost certainly reflect a failure to get the privatekey passphrase from you. GnuPG, or in recent versions (I think 2.1, definitely 2.2) more specifically gpg-agent, has a number of ways it can get passphrases based on the environment it runs in (terminal vs window manager etc.), and it appears yours is either set incorrectly for your environment or otherwise malfunctioning; termux may indeed be relevant here, and I know almost nothing about it. To narrow this down I suggest you try a simpler case of encrypting a file, where you can get additional information:

```
echo test | gpg -e -r to_whom -o tempfile; gpg -v -d tempfile
```

You could also add `--status-fd=1` -- the additional information added on my system isn't helpful, but it might be on yours. If the agent appears to be running but malfunctioning, do `gpg-connect-agent killagent /bye` and if successful retry the decrypt-file operation to see if there are now any difference(s).

While I'm not sure, I have seen cases in the past where after a decryption failure GPG got confused about other things, which *might* explain the `encrypted packet with unknown version`. At minimum fixing the passphrase for decryption issue should allow focussing on any remaining error.